# Запуск python на сервере linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, gnu-screen

Нужно запустить python3 script на сервере с Ubuntu чтобы при завершении сессии ssh продолжал работать. Сейчас делаю через screen но он иногда вылетает, примерно рас в  4 дня. Какие есть способы решить эту проблему?

Comment: screen не может вылетать сам по себе. У всего есть причина.

Comment: Логично предположить, что если screen вылетает по какой-то причине, то и другие способы запуска будут вылетать по той же самой причине. Так что вам сперва нужно выяснить причину, почему вылетает. У меня вот python-скрипты работают в screen по 400 дней подряд и не вылетают

Comment: у меня в системд сразу. почему вылетело смотрю в журнале. оч удобно.

Comment: Могу предположить что сервер перезапускается.  Тогда как сделать чтобы при запуске машины запускался screen и python3 скрипт в нём?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишите сервис, если скрипт не интерактивный. В /etc/systemd/system/pythonserver.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Python Server
After=зависимость.service
Requires=зависимость.service
BindsTo=зависимость.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /путь/скрипт.py
WorkingDirectory=/путь/
Restart=always
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Укажите питона с полным путем и каталог откуда запускаться. Зависимости указать можно 3мя способами(по разному работают). Например сервер баз данных делаем через BindsTo.

```
systemctl enable pythonserver.service
systemctl start pythonserver.service
```

Вывод программы смотреть через

```
journalctl -u pythonserver -e -f
```

Comment: Если запускать автономный скрипт, то все идеально. Если запускать скрипт из сложного по структуре проекта то можно еще добавить `Environment=PYTHONPATH=/путь/папки/с/проектом` и если скрипту нужен выход в сеть то `After=network.target`

Comment: WorkingDirectory обычно достаточно и pythonpath не нужен